# What software to use in creating Android apps that have the ability to do image processing?

Tags: android, library, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am now trying to create an Android app where the app can detect a specific image or object using image processing.

Is there any specific software or tools that I can use in order to develop my program? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure 2D manipulation, have a look at OpenCV for Android:
https://opencv.org/android/

If AugmentedReality is what you're looking for, here is a list of SDKs:
https://www.digifloor.com/best-ar-sdk-android-ios-07

It comprises the most well known:
* Google ARCore - https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk
* Apple ARKit - https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/